# How to free memory returned by glxChooseFBConfig?

Tags: c, free, xlib, address-sanitizer, glx

`glxChooseFBConfig` returns `GLXFBConfig*` and `GLXFBConfig` is defined this way:

```
typedef struct __GLXFBConfigRec *GLXFBConfig;
```

Here is an example function which uses `glxChooseFBConfig` and frees memory:

```
void fun()
{
    const int attribs[] =
    {
        GLX_RENDER_TYPE, GLX_RGBA_BIT,
        GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE, GLX_WINDOW_BIT,
        GLX_X_VISUAL_TYPE, GLX_TRUE_COLOR,
        GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, True,
        GLX_RED_SIZE, 8,
        GLX_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
        GLX_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
        GLX_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
        GLX_DEPTH_SIZE, 24,
        GLX_STENCIL_SIZE, 8,
        None
    };

    Display* dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    int count = 0;
    GLXFBConfig* fbconfigs = glXChooseFBConfig(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy), attribs, &count);

    //do something with fbconfigs

    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        XFree(fbconfigs[i]);
    }

    XFree(fbconfigs);
}
```

I compile my application with flag `-fsanitize=address`. When I run the application I get a sanitizer error: `attempting double-free` What is wrong ?

Comment: From looking at the [documentation](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glXChooseFBConfig.xml), you just need to scrap the `for` loop. (Generally, when allocating arrays, you free them simply *via* the actual array pointer.)

Comment: Why are you calling `XFree` on each element in the contiguous array.  You just need `XFree(fbconfigs); `.

Comment: Does glXChooseFBConfig return **  type ? I have thought that array and each element in the array have been allocated using malloc.

Comment: See the documentation I linked: The C specification is `GLXFBConfig * glXChooseFBConfig(...`

Comment: The underlying type of each element in the array may well be a pointer itself, but that's opaque as far as the API goes: they probably point to internal memory that's managed by the GLX code itself and so must not be freed.

Comment: @G.M. this should be an answer, so that we can upvote it.